# How to define first and last object and stop the loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am sharing a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kiirosora/yqxezatg/) with you guys and on there, if you focus on the input field and move the keyboard arrow down key, it will start selecting the items.

Once you reach the last it takes you to up again.

I want to restrict it is such a way that: if you are on the last item it wont start again from top and gives `alert('no more!')`, and remains on the last; and when arrow up to the first, it won't start from the last again and remains on the first.

Comment: I see it working in fiddle

Comment: i want to stop it at last and at first, i am sorry i am very weak in javascript, the logic doesn't enter my mind :(

Comment: can you please update the fiddle for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The followings are the neccessary changes in the body of the `Navigate` function. Instead of this:

```
if (displayBoxIndex >= oBoxCollection.length)
    displayBoxIndex = 0;
if (displayBoxIndex < 0)
    displayBoxIndex = oBoxCollection.length - 1;
```

You need to have this block of code:

```
if (displayBoxIndex >= oBoxCollection.length)
    displayBoxIndex = oBoxCollection.length - 1;
if (displayBoxIndex < 0)
    displayBoxIndex = 0;
```

The alert would look like this:

```
if (displayBoxIndex >= oBoxCollection.length) {
    alert('no more!');
    displayBoxIndex = oBoxCollection.length - 1;
}
```

Comment: and how do i alert(no more!) when arrow try to move more down from the last?

Comment: i am confused, everyone gave the right answer at once, selecting anyone would be maybe unfair for others so lets keep it unanswered or let the management decide.

Comment: Thats for your valueable time you,and all of the people has given. :)

Answer (score 2):

In your JS code there is a function called Navigate... This controls what happens when a key is pressed.

The code below is responsible for moving the cursor back to the beginning once the limit has been reached.

```
if (displayBoxIndex >= oBoxCollection.length)
     displayBoxIndex = 0;
if (displayBoxIndex < 0)
     displayBoxIndex = oBoxCollection.length - 1;
```

If you want the cursor to stop at the last box, and alert the user, change the first if statement to this...

```
if (displayBoxIndex >= oBoxCollection.length){
displayBoxIndex = displayBoxIndex  - 1;
alert("no more!");}
```

Using these functions, you can manipulate what happens when the cursor goes out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : You can check for first and last element using `:first` and `:last`

```
var Navigate = function(diff) {
    displayBoxIndex += diff;
    var oBoxCollection = $(".qss.selected");

    if(oBoxCollection.length==0)
    {
        $(".qss:first").addClass('selected');
    }
    else if((diff==1 && oBoxCollection.is(':last')) || (diff==-1 && oBoxCollection.index()==0))
    {
        alert('No More!');
        return false;
    }
    else if(diff==1)
    { oBoxCollection.removeClass('selected').next('.qss').addClass('selected');
    }
    else if(diff==-1)
    { oBoxCollection.removeClass('selected').prev('.qss').addClass('selected');
    }
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kawadkarbk31/yqxezatg/16/)**

Answer (score 0):

Make these changes, instead of assigning the displayboxindex to 0 again.

```
if (displayBoxIndex >= oBoxCollection.length){
       //1.  
            alert("No More..")
        //2.  
             return
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the Navigate method like below,

```
var Navigate = function(diff) {

   displayBoxIndex += diff;
   var oBoxCollection = $(".qss");
   if(displayBoxIndex<0){
      displayBoxIndex=0;
      alert("no more");
   }
   if(displayBoxIndex>=oBoxCollection.length){
      displayBoxIndex=oBoxCollection.length-1;
      alert("no more"); 
   }

   var cssClass = "selected";
   oBoxCollection.removeClass(cssClass).eq(displayBoxIndex).addClass(cssClass);
}
```